# vim terminal linewrap in normal mode

Tags: vimrc, terminal

So suppose there's some text in vim terminal that is longer than the terminal width and it causes a wrap. Now suppose I go into normal mode in that terminal.

[image]

In normal mode, we have an addition of 4 new rows due to line numbers and spaces

[image]

This causes an awkward break in the line we saw before, which now takes 3 lines when it can still fit in 2 lines

[image]

Is there a solution to this? through a vim setting or a terminal setting?

This happens to me in different shells (bash/tcsh) different terminals emulators (windows terminal/mate terminal) in vim 8.1

Comment: Why do you enable numbering for terminal window?

Comment: 1. I don't know how to configure settings specifically for terminal. my vimrc enables numbers unconditionally - if you know how to do that I'll appreciate it (maybe I will set nowrap for terminal).
2. it's easier to navigate when I have number and relative number set.

Comment: Try `:au TerminalWinOpen * :set nonu`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the following autocommand to disable numbering in terminal windows:

```
augroup MyTerminal
au!
au TerminalWinOpen * :set nonumber norelativenumber
augroup END
```

Note: TerminalWinOpen does not exist in Neovim.

Comment: I used it to set nowrap which solves it as well, and keeps the numbers which I like.
The wrap is still there due to terminal wrap, but the awkward break is gone.